# Syncing iCal and Address Book over several macs?

Tags: mac, sync, calendar.app

I'm looking for a way to keep my calendars and Address Book in sync. Can anyone recommend a way? I want to keep all the data as it is, though I don't want to use MobileMe.

Answer (score 3):

http://fruux.com/ is the **free** MobileMe alternative for **exactly** that kind of setup.

And of course you could sync to the same Google address book and calendar, though when I tried that, there was always some information not sync'ed really well. But that was maybe just me.
If you are interested, there are lots of how-to's out there, one being here: [klick](http://sellingexpectations.com/2008/07/using-google-as-a-free-mobileme-alternative-with-push-contacts-calendar/)

Hope I could help.

Comment: FWIW, Google sync for contacts only is available and occurs when you plug in an iPod or iPhone if using Mac OS X 10.5. In 10.6 it will now sync hourly if you have it set up because you have an iPod touch/iPhone.

Comment: Currently not very happy with fruux for multiple reasons.

Answer (score 2):

[iSynCal](http://ww2.unime.it/flr/isyncal/en/index.html) and [Address-O-Sync](http://www.slamslash.com/address-o-sync/) do the job. Both are free.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using BusySync from http://www.busymac.com, it costs about US$39 per Mac.
Syncs Macs on a LAN and w/ Google Calendar